# Flags not showing up

Tags: bug, moderation

Flags don't show up when I refresh the page.

This happens regularly. 
I switch to the tab in chrome with the site already up.

I refresh the page by hitting the reload button, or clicking on the logo. No flags show up, by that I mean I don't get the yellow circle with the number indicating there are flags in the queue.

Some time after that say one hour later I do the same thing and a flag shows up that's 12 hours old. This flag should have shown up an hour ago when I refreshed the page.

I have tried refreshing the page with the reload button, clicking on the logo, clicking on the load new questions bar. It doesn't really matter how I refresh the page sometimes the flags just don't show up.

Comment: That's because I'm too quick on the draw.  Flagged for review and BAZING!  Bob's on the job!

Comment: Larry - how do you know there are actual flags in the queue when you refresh?

Comment: @Oded I have edited the quesiton to make it more clear (I think) Let me know if you need more or better info.

Comment: @Oded Don't know if it help but it did it again just now. I refreshed to home page no flags, then I clicked on a question when the question loaded I was notified of a flag that was 3 hours old. Shouldn't it have shown up when I refreshed the home page. Here is the post that was flagged http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/7232/85

Comment: @Larry - can you tell what browser and OS you are on and what versions of both?

Comment: @Oded Chrome Version 29.0.1547.66 m, Win XP Pro Version 2002 Service pack 3 (Don't laugh, it's corporate and I have no control on that one)

Comment: More likely to cry. My sympathies. But it does make me wonder if the issue is one of corporate network/firewalls/caches that don't respect caching directives.

Comment: @Oded I think but am not sure it does it on my home computer and laptop, both running chrome and Windows 8

Comment: It would be great if you could confirm either way - at least so we can rule out network/ISP issues.

Comment: Just saw the same bug: IE8 running on Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: @Oded It does do it away from my work network. I am using Windows 8 and Chrome on my laptop and get the same problem

Comment: @Oded And on my desktop at home, Windows 8 and Chrome.

Comment: @Oded Still doing it, I refreshed the page no flags. Immediately click on a question when the page loads I get the yellow circle with 3 flags.

Comment: You may have noticed the new top bar on meta.so - that will get rolled out to the entire network soon. If this still happens with it (there was a lot of backend work done for the new top bar, so it is entirely possible that this will not longer be an issue). Let me know if this is not the case.